# Which determiner is correct, "this" or "the" in "this/the same key"?

Tags: definite-articles, determiners

I am helping a friend edit a manuscript for an informal reference book about music. There are occasional instances where determiners are being used in a way that I find unfamiliar or awkward. I'm unsure if it's subjective preference, or if there is a technical error. Here is an example sentence (it is preceded by an image of a portion of a piano keyboard with an arrow pointing to a particular key):

> Notice where that key is on the piano. Whether we flatten the note above or sharpen the note below, it ends up taking us to this same key.

I recommended changing "this" to "the" near the end of the sentence: "...it ends up taking us to the same key."

However I am unsure what technical reason, if any, to make this recommendation, other than it sounds more correct to me.

Is there any reason to prefer "the" over "this" in this example?

Comment: You have a point. I'd use *that* both times, or *this* both times.

Comment: Presumably there is something earlier in the text indicating which key ***that** key* is. It may point to a single key by name, or to the result of some earlier instruction, like "find a black key". Once a particular key is designated, you can use _this_ or _the_, no difference, except for the fact that _this_ contrasts with _that_. You can also use _that_ again, since you've used it before and it still refers to the same key. In fact, that's what I would recommend.

Comment: @JohnLawler Indeed there is; an image with an arrow pointing to a specific black key precedes the text.

Comment: There's a problem not addressed in the extract given; 'Whether we flat the note above ...'. But the note above _what_? The treatment at [Europianosnaples.com/piano-keys](https://www.europianosnaples.com/piano-keys-101/#:~:text=The%2012%20notes%20are%20C,and%20flats%20are%20black%20keys) seems easy to follow (with the exception of an ungrammatical sentence). // 'This' is more accurate here, pointing to 'that' key already mentioned, though some might think this usage over-formal.

Comment: Whether we flatten the note above (move down a semitone) or sharpen the note below (move up a semitone) it takes you to the same key. (So A♭ and G♯ refer to the same key).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You're correct in that the "above what" isn't covered well by the example. WeatherVane hit it precisely, in that the text is referring to moving up and down in pitch (semitones) which is covered in earlier sections of the text.

Comment: Whether the keys are black or white makes no difference (although it's perhaps easier to see when pointing to a black key). Similar would apply when pointing to the E key. It's one semitone less than F and one more than D♯.

Comment: @WeatherVane The text at this point is extremely introductory and is thus using a black key rather than a natural note. I could potentially modify the example to eliminate this additional bit of detail, but I think it's best ignored for the sake of the main question point.

Comment: So is it explaining what 'flat' and 'sharp' mean?

Comment: @WeatherVane Those explanations preceded this text, so the reader should already know what they mean.

Comment: 'Flat' and 'sharp' bother me far more than the, that or this. Flatten & sharpen, as corrected in passing by Weather Vane.

Comment: @Tetsujin In music, "sharp" and "flat" can be verbs. I've certainly heard such usage from musicians, and Merriam Webster's [sharp definition 4](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sharp) and [flat definition 4](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flat) seem to agree.

Comment: By that definition, I could equally use a whetstone to sharp my knife. It's sharpen & flatten.

Comment: @Tetsujin You're not wrong, but in music it's common to hear, for example, "Let's sharp the F note for a Lydian feel." I didn't ask about this particular detail, but I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: @JYelton - Not in any musical circles I've worked in for the past 50 years, sorry. Maybe it's a transpondian difference. I'm UK.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147940/discussion-between-jyelton-and-tetsujin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***This same note*** is not wrong, it is slightly literary and emphatic. It was used in the KJV Bible. For example:

> The king of Babylon set himself against Jerusalem ***this same*** day.
>   (Ezek. 24:2 KJV)

However, in such a context such emphasis may not be needed. I personally would also replace ***this*** with ***the***, to match the language register and also to avoid the reader stumbling on a [less common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=this%20same%2C%20the%20same&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) expression.

Comment: I'd say it's more acceptable to replace 'this' with 'the' in the Ezekiel quote; the two variants are tight synonyms. (Actually, I'd use 'that very'.) But using 'the' in OP's example is not absolutely constrained to mean 'that key in both cases' (though it would be the more likely interpretation).

Comment: If I show you "This same can of dogfood costs only $1.49 at PetTown" or something along those lines, would you change "literary" to something else?